# how to deploy angular and express project to google app engine

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express, google-app-engine

I want to deploy my app to google app engine, I have setup app engine already and install gcloud in my local machine. I am able deploy some projects already but for only angular.

I want to understand how we should deploy a complete app (server and client) on app engine. client connects to server via /api endpoint

here is my folder structure:

```
-project
 -client
  -dist
 -server
```

backend serves with /api

is there any article or document from where i can get some help.

Answer (score 0):

1. [This](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine/hello-world/standard) is a link to a sample Node.js App for GAE Standard directly from Google. The sample uses `express`
2. To deploy both client and server, I believe you'll have to create them as different `services` and deploy them separately. A Google search brought this [example](https://medium.com/@rgoyard/how-to-deploy-a-single-page-application-and-its-backend-to-google-app-engine-353ff93bd38c) published on medium. If you need an introduction/primer to `services`, see this [writeup](https://nocommandline.com/blog/managing-large-apps-on-google-app-engine/) on our blog. (note: next version of our App will have support for deploying multiple services)